# When i maximize my window my script fails

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, fullscreen, maximize

I have written a script in java for a website. The script is working fine and doing every step as per the expected requirements. But when i maximise the window by the command " //driver.manage().window().maximize(); " - the script fails in somewhere middle. The same situation occurs when i use the full screen mode.

**Note : The script works completely great in normal mode.**

Comment: can you share the error log

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately on some environments (like inside docker), maximize wont be working properly. Also when using maximize you won't know exactly what size of your window would be.

It is more safe to use:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
```